# Terraform : Is it possible to interpolate or loop through ressources from a list within the output block?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to output gcp project information by doing something like this :

```
output "projects" {
  value = tomap({
    for project_name in ["project_1", "project_2", "project_3"] :
    project_name => tomap({
      id     = google_project."${project_name}".id
      number = google_project."${project_name}".number
    })
  })
  description = "Projects"
}
```

Or like this :

```
output "projects" {
  value = tomap({
    for_each = toset([google_project.project_1,google_project.project_2])
    id       = each.key.id
    number   = each.key.number

  })
  description = "Projects"
}
```

Is it at all possible to use resource names this way? Do I have to specify every resource by duplicating code?

E.g.

```
output "projects" {
  value = tomap({
    project_1 = tomap({
      id     = google_project.project_1.id
      number = google_project.project_1.number
    })
    project_2 = tomap({
      id     = google_project.project_2.id
      number = google_project.project_2.number
    })
    project_3 = tomap({
      id     = google_project.project_3 .id
      number = google_project.pproject_3 .number
    })
  })
  description = "Projects"
}
```

EDIT : declared resources.

In `main.tf` projects 1 to 3 are declared the same way.

```
resource "google_project" "project_3" {
  name                = var.projects.project_3.name
  project_id          = var.projects.project_3.id
  folder_id           = google_folder.parent.name
  billing_account     = data.google_billing_account.acct.id
  auto_create_network = false
}
```

in `variables.tf`

```
variable "projects" {
  type = map(object({
    name = string
    id   = string
  }))
}
```

in `variables.tfvars`

```
projects = {
  project_1= {
    name = "project_1"
    id   = "project_1-12345"
  }  
  project_2= {
    name = "project_2"
    id   = "project_2-12345"
  }
  project_3= {
    name = "project_2"
    id   = "project_2-12345"
  }
}
```

Comment: No, you could use `for_each` probably, but there is information missing from the question. Can you add the resources to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misunderstood your question originally. I see now that you want to reference a resource by a variable name. No you cannot do that. But your setup here doesn't really make sense, and seems more complex than it needs to be.

Consider if these options would improve your setup.

```
locals {
  projects = { # This is equivalent to your input.
    project_1 = {
      name = "project_1"
      id   = "project_1-12345"
    }
    project_2 = {
      name = "project_2"
      id   = "project_2-12345"
    }
    project_3 = {
      name = "project_3"
      id   = "project_3-12345"
    }
  }
}

resource "google_project" "this" {
  for_each = local.projects

  name                = each.key # or each.value.name / don't really need name
  project_id          = each.value.id
  folder_id           = google_folder.parent.name
  billing_account     = data.google_billing_account.acct.id
  auto_create_network = false
}

output "projects_from_input" {
  description = "You can of course, just use the input."
  value       = local.projects
}

output "projects_explicit_values" {
  description = "Alternatively, if you need a subset of resource values."
  value = { for k, v in google_project.this : k => {
    name = v.name
    id   = v.project_id
  } }
}

output "complete_resources" {
  description = "But you can just output the complete resource."
  value       = google_project.this
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I got it right because I get an error :
`Error: Invalid reference
...
A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.`

Comment: Can you provide an example to how you would write the output file with your method?

Comment: @Imad: I updated the answer. I originally misunderstood you. Maybe this will help.

Answer (score 2):

I edited my initial answer after seeing the `Terraform` resource that creates a project. The need is a way to get a resource name in the output bloc with interpolation.

I think if a single resource is used to create all the projets instead of one resource per projet, it's easier to expose this resource in the output bloc.

For example you can configure `projects` metadata information from a json file, or directly a local variable or a `var` if needed :

Example for a json file and local variable

mymodule/resource/projects.json :

```json
{
    "projects": {
        "project_1": {
            "id": "project_1",
            "number": "23333311"
        },
        "project_2": {
            "id": "project_2",
            "number": "33399999"
        }
    }
}
```

Then retrieve `projects` as a variable from `locals.tf` file :

mymodule/locals.tf :

```
locals {
  projects = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/resource/projects.json"))["projects"]
}
```

Create your projects in a single resource with a foreach :

```
resource "google_project" "projects" {
  for_each           = local.projects
  name                = each.key
  project_id          = each.value["id"]
  folder_id           = google_folder.parent.name
  billing_account     = data.google_billing_account.acct.id
  auto_create_network = false
}
```

Expose the projects `resource` in an `output.tf` file :

```
output "projects" {
  value = google_project.projects
  description = "Projects"
}
```

The same principle can be done with a `var` instead of local variable.

Comment: yes, but then I wouldn't be getting them from a resource block, but from a `tfvars` like file, and I wouldn't be able to call on the project `id` and/or `number` as they were instantiated after the creation. The purpose is to skip the redundancy of inputing the `id` and `number` values myself, but to get them from terraform.

Comment: Ok I understand, in your output, I think you can use `foreach` with `each.key`. An example from this link : (exemple with Set of String) https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each

Comment: nope can't use `for_each` in `output` module apparently. I get an error :  `The "each" object can be used only in "module" or "resource" blocks, and only when the "for_each" argument is set.`

Comment: Ok sorry, I thought it was possible.

Comment: Hi Imad, I edited my first answer, I thinks it's easier for you if you use a single `Terraform` resource that creates all the projects (with `foreach`). It's also easier then to expose this resource with an `output`. My example uses `locals variable` and json conf, but you can replace it with a `var`.